# Setting src for html5 audio object that not working in direct access?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know that is it possible that we define a SRC in Audio Object (html5) that user can not access to it directly and just working in player?

I thought about an "extra token" or "hashing" but not sure that Audio Object accept such things.
In fact I want to prevent download managers from opening popup window for desktop users

with the best

Comment: For content to be presented on a client machine it has to be downloaded. There's nothing you can do to encrypt the data at that point. The old adage is true for this case: if you want something to remain private, don't put it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use blob data. Download Managers usually won't show a message to download in this case.

Comment: But it needs to fetch whole file first, is it right?